# Understanding OpenSceneGraph AddChild in an other thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, openscenegraph

I am replacing the OpenGL code of my C++ app with code that uses OpenSceneGraph.

The app is based on Qt and using Qt Threads.

The main thread is calling the `viewer->frame()` while other threads are loading data.

Those threads directly works whith my scene graph, adding node with `addChild()`.

But sometimes this `group->addChild` call make my app crash. I Can see, in the stacktrace, the group's vector containing the children is resizing.

I guess that I'm not supposed to add childrens in one thread while another may be drawing it. Am I right ?

What is the best way to do it ? Using a update callback ? Locking the main thread ?

Comment: It's even worse: you're not allowed to use any classes (whether in OSG or Qt) from multiple threads without locking unless they're documented as thread-safe. There are many possible approaches to multithreaded use of OSG. The question is likely too broad without some clarification and code examples.

Comment: That is the answer I needed, thanks.